# Kendo UI Menu items select issue

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

Issue: Clicking on the image in the kendo menu item, the select event is not triggering.

what i have tried: See the sample code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/images">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <h4>Menu with images</h4>
            <ul id="menu-images"></ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#menu-images").kendoMenu({
                dataSource: [
                {
                    text: "Golf", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/sports/golf.png",
                    items: [
                    { 
                        text: "Top News", 
                        imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/star.png",
                        select: function (e) {
                            alert('Clicking on image select event is not triggering')
                        }
                    },
                    { text: "Photo Galleries", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/photo.png" },
                    { text: "Videos Records", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/video.png" },
                    { text: "Radio Records", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/speaker.png" }]
                },]
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #menu-sprites .k-sprite {
                background-image: url("../content/shared/styles/flags.png");
            }
            .brazilFlag {
                background-position: 0 0;
            }
            .indiaFlag {
                background-position: 0 -32px;
            }
            .netherlandsFlag {
                background-position: 0 -64px;
            }
            .historyIcon {
                background-position: 0 -96px;
            }
            .geographyIcon {
                background-position: 0 -128px;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Description:

I have edited this code sample taken from Telerik demo. in the above code i have added the items for Golf. that also have the select function which is what i am talking about. after executing this. **If i click on the text "Top News" the alert will trigger.The alert is not working when i click/select on the image.**

Posting in Telerik forum is only applicable for licensed users. I dont have.

Let me know if any body come across these kind of issue.

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have nested the event-declaration within the dataSource-item.

Just move the declaration to the menu-level and it should work.

```
$("#menu-images").kendoMenu({
            select: function(e) {
              alert($(e.item).children('.k-link').text())                
            }
            dataSource: [
            {
                text: "Golf", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/sports/golf.png",
                items: [
                { 
                    text: "Top News", 
                    imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/star.png"
                },
                { text: "Photo Galleries", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/photo.png" },
                { text: "Videos Records", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/video.png" },
                { text: "Radio Records", imageUrl: "../content/shared/icons/16/speaker.png" }]
            },]
        });
```

Using `$(e.item)` you can go further and figure out which item has been selected. Have a look the event-section of the online-demo. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/events